# array address when pushed to stack

Tags: assembly

I wrote a simple c function:

```
void function(){
    int n;
    char s[6];
    n = 1;
    s[0] = 2;
    s[5] = 3;
}
```

This disassembles to:

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
sub $40, %esp
movl $1, -12(%esp)
movb $2, -40(%esp)
movb $3, -35($esp)
leave
ret
```

I am trying to understand why the char[] is given the address that starts at -40.

it is a 6 byte array, so I would think that it would require 8 bytes (multiple of 4-byte word), in which case it would be assigned to the memory address -20(%esp)

Why -40(%esp)?

Thanks

EDIT:  I am also under the assumption that n is given the offset of -12(%esp) because ints and registers are 4 bytes, and eip is pushed to -4(%esp) and ebp is pushed to -8(%esp).  Is this correct?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What OS and compiler? I cannot reproduce using gcc on linux or the mingw port of gcc on Win7. I assume -35($esp) should be -35(%esp)

Comment: This occurs on a red hat 7.3 box.  I also ran this on Ubuntu 10 x64 and the locations are n = -4(%rbp) s[0] = -16(%rbp) and s[5] = -11(%rbp).  Both versions were compiled using GCC, version 2.96 on the red hat machine, version 4.4.1 on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Your Ubuntu machine output concurs with mine. I wonder if this is just an issue with that old GCC version. It seems GCC 2.96 is not a [formal release](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.96.html).

Answer (score 1):

There should be  movl $1, -12(%**ebp**) and so on.

s[] is a buffer, so compiler may allocate additional space for security checks (but there isn't any checks).

There is the following layout:

```
esp+44: ebp+04: return address
esp+40: ebp+00: prev ebp value
.......
esp+12: ebp-12: n
.......
esp+04: esp-3C: s[4:6]
esp+00: ebp-40: s[0:4]
```